# I want to display the entered ID information

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

[image: my app interface]

I want to view entered edittext area with entered ID number. But my app is stopping.

```java
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user";
    public static final String  TABLE_NAME = "userTable";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL3 = "EMAIL";
    public static final String COL4 = "TV";

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null , 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME+ "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " NAME VARCHAR , EMAIL VARCHAR , TV VARCHAR)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String dropTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXİSTS "+ TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(dropTable);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public  boolean addData(String name,String email,String tvShow){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,email);
        contentValues.put(COL4,tvShow);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

        if(result == -1 ){
            return  false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor showData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor SecileniGetir(String gelen){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  ID = "+ gelen,null );
        return data;
    }

    public boolean Update(String id,String name , String email,String tvShow){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1,id);
        contentValues.put(COL2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,email);
        contentValues.put(COL4,tvShow);
       if(COL1.toString()==""){
           return false;
       }else {
           db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
           return true;
       }
    }
}
```

I created a `DatabaseHelper` class. I created `dataAdd` function , `dataUpgrade` function , and i wanna create a funciton while  user entered id , other information view on own editText area.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private EditText etName,etMail,etFavorite,etId;
    private Button addDataButton,viewData,update;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etId = findViewById(R.id.etId);
        update = findViewById(R.id.update);
        etMail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etFavorite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFavorite);
        addDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addData);
        viewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewData);

        AddData();
       SecileniGoster();
        Update();


    }

    public void AddData(){
        addDataButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email  = etMail.getText().toString();
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String favorite = etFavorite.getText().toString();

                if(email.equals("")||name.equals("")||favorite.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lütfen Tüm alanları Doldurunuz!! Kayıt Başarısız", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {

                    boolean insert = dbHelper.addData(name, email, favorite);

                    if (insert == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Başarılı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Başarısız", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }

            }
        });
    }


    public void ViewData(){
        viewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor data = dbHelper.showData();
                if(data.getCount() == 0){
                    //message
                    showMessage("Error","Data Not Found!!!");

                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("ID" + data.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Name : " + data.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Email : " + data.getString(2)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Favorite Ch : "+ data.getString(3)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("\n");
                    showMessage("All Stored Data ", buffer.toString());

                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void SecileniGoster(){

        viewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String id = etId.getText().toString();
                Cursor data = dbHelper.SecileniGetir(id);
                etName.setText(data.getString(1));
                etMail.setText(data.getString(2));
                etFavorite.setText(data.getString(3));
            }
        });

    }



    public void showMessage(String title, String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setCancelable(true);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.show();
    }


    public void Update(){
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email  = etMail.getText().toString();
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String favorite = etFavorite.getText().toString();
                String id = etId.getText().toString();
                int getID = etId.getText().toString().length();
                if(getID>0){
                    boolean update = dbHelper.Update(id,name,email,favorite); 
                    if(update == true){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Succesfuly updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        etName.setText("");
                        etMail.setText("");
                        etFavorite.setText("");
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unfortunatelly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Girilen Id bulunamadi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

RESULT
[image: result output]

Result Output

```
2020-07-15 14:35:09.398 24815-24815/com.tcoding.sqlitesaveuserdata E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tcoding.sqlitesaveuserdata, PID: 24815
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:515)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:52)
    at com.tcoding.sqlitesaveuserdata.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:102)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Hi ! Why is your app stopping ? Can you give and error ? Also you can add "!" to your images link so that they are displayed in the post

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the error as text, so that it easier to read?